# Delete Azure Blobs in subfolder in C# - without deleting the subfolder

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure container 'MyContainer' then 'under' it,  I have 'subfolders' called ProcessingFiles. So the 'structure' looks like this

**MyContainer\ProcessingFiles\SampleFile.xml**

I want to delete 'SampleFile.xml' - but when I run the following code the 'ProcessingFiles' folder is also deleted.

```
 //connect to azure  container
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_BlobConnectionstring);

            var myClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = myClient.GetContainerReference(MyContainer");

            container.CreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob);

            _blobabspath = container.Uri.AbsoluteUri;

            foreach (IListBlobItem blobItem in container.ListBlobs())
            {
                if (blobItem is CloudBlobDirectory)
                {
                    CloudBlobDirectory directory = (CloudBlobDirectory)blobItem;
                    if (directory.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("ProcessingFolder))
                    {
                        IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = directory.ListBlobs(true);
                        ICloudBlob bi;
                        foreach (var blob in blobs)
                        {
                            if (blob is CloudBlockBlob)
                            {
                                bi = blob as CloudBlockBlob;
                                if (bi.Name.Contains(".xml"))
                                {
                                   Log.Info($"Deleting XML file : {bi.Name} from {_processingfolder}");
                                   bi.Delete();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

**How do I JUST delete the single XML file - and not include the subfolder 'ProcessingFolder'?**

**What am I missing?  thx in advance**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Storage doesn't have subfolders, only containers and blobs. Azure Storage gives you something that *looks* like folders via the delimiter character (letting you do specific searches, for instance).

Your blob's name is actually `ProcessingFiles\SampleFile.xml`. This is why it appears that the subfolder disappears when you delete the blob.

Just to drive the point home a bit further: let's say you had a thousand blobs, spread across multiple "subfolders" and you tried filtering on just the one subfolder (`ProcessingFiles` in your case). The search would still scan all thousand blobs, filtering on the prefix part of the name you specified.